# Using BIOS int 0x15/E820 to view the memory map

Tags: memory, bios, memory-management, acpi, x86

I am doing some baremetal programming on x86. I am in 16 bit mode and I emulate using qemu... I use int 0x15/ax = 0xE820 to view the memory map... Using the qemu monitor (to examine the region where I wrote the map) I get the following information about the memorymap:

```
Start=0 Length= 0x9fc00 (type 1)
Start=0x9fc00 Length= 0x400 (type 2) 
Start=0xf0000 Length= 0x10000 (type 2)
Start=0x100000 Length= 0x7ee0000 (type 1)
Start=0x7fe0000 Length= 0x10000 (type 2)
Start=0xfffc0000 Length = 0x40000 (Type 2)
```

So, are the segments that are not in this map (Eg. 0xA0000) belong to something like MMIO? I know that type 2 memory regions are used by BIOS, etc. ( **Start=0x9fc00 Length= 0x400 (type 2)** is EDBA) What happens when I write to these regions?

Note: I don't have type 3(ACPI) probably because I'm using qemu. In real hardware I most probably should get type 3 regions too. Is that RAM also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This BIOS call is filly described in
[INT 15h, AX=E820h - Query System Address Map](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/mem64mb.html),
where it is noted in the section "Assumptions and Limitations":

> 1. The BIOS will return address ranges describing base board memory and ISA or PCI memory that is contiguous with that baseboard memory.
> 2. The BIOS WILL NOT return a range description for the memory mapping of PCI devices, ISA Option ROM's, and ISA plug & play cards. This is
>      because the OS has mechanisms available to detect them.
> 3. The BIOS will return chipset defined address holes that are not being used by devices as reserved.
> 4. Address ranges defined for base board memory mapped I/O devices (for example APICs) will be returned as reserved.
> 5. All occurrences of the system BIOS will be mapped as reserved. This includes the area below 1 MB, at 16 MB (if present) and at end of the
>      address space (4 gig).
> 6. Standard PC address ranges will not be reported. Example video memory at A0000 to BFFFF physical will not be described by this
>      function. The range from E0000 to EFFFF is base board specific and
>      will be reported as suits the bas board.
> 7. All of lower memory is reported as normal memory. It is OS's responsibility to handle standard RAM locations reserved for specific
>      uses, for example: the interrupt vector table(0:0) and the BIOS data
>      area(40:0).

The Wikipedia article
[Detecting Memory (x86)](https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29)
add in its section
"BIOS Function: INT 0x15, EAX = 0xE820"
adds the following rules:

> - After getting the list, it may be desirable to: sort the list, combine adjacent ranges of the same type, change any overlapping areas
>     to the most restrictive type, and change any unrecognised "type"
>     values to type 2.
> - Type 3 "ACPI reclaimable" memory regions may be used like (and combined with) normal "available RAM" areas as long as you're finished
>     using the ACPI tables that are stored there (i.e. it can be
>     "reclaimed").
> - Types 2, 4, 5 (reserved, ACPI non-volatile, bad) mark areas that should be avoided when you are allocating physical memory.
> - Treat unlisted regions as Type 2 -- reserved.
> - Your code must be able to handle areas that don't start or end on any sort of "page boundary".

Conclusion: The ranges that are not found in the map are functional,
perhaps occupied by device memory such as video.

Comment: What does Baseboard memory mean? RAM sticks? Is the memory mapped to PCI/ISA devices Memory Mapped I/O? In short, what's RAM and what's not?

Comment: You would find that in Wikipedia [Conventional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_memory): "In DOS memory management, conventional memory, also called base memory, is the first 640 kilobytes (640×1024 bytes) of the memory on IBM PC or compatible systems". You are dealing here with terms from the antiquity of computers.